# How is $ \ \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}=\ \frac{x^2}{1+x^2} = \ 1 - \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How did $$ \ \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}$$ become $$\ \frac{x^2}{1+x^2} = \ 1 - \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$$

I am trying to figure out the equation.

Answer (score 7):

$$\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}=\frac{x^2}{x^2}\times\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}=\frac{x^2}{x^2(1+\frac{1}{x^2})}=\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}=\frac{x^2+1-1}{x^2+1}=1-\frac{1}{x^2+1}$$ So, probably a typo somewhere.

Comment: You are very welcome !